# adding a jqgrid column that is a result of two other columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to sum the column values of a jqGrid table.I have four columns in my jqGrid`"SL", "Item", "Quantity", "Rate","Amount"`,where `Amount` is the result of `Quantity*Rate` this multiplication is not a query retrieved data.It is done inside the javascript code.Now I want to sum the amount column.Summation is showing correctly.I've checked it with an alert but when I tried to set it on footer row`$grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 'amountcalculate': parseFloat(colSum)});` it is showing `NAN`.why is it not working.I have used footer row earlier and did summation.It worked perfectly.When I tried to add the column value which is a result of two other columns then it does not work.
Here is my code

```
  subGrid : true,
        subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowid) {
            var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
            $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'></table>");
            $("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
                datatype: "json",
                    url: "/bbbb/regfgfgfisterFgshGood        /listReceivableOrderDetails?id=" + rowid,
                     colNames: ["SL", "Item", "Quantity", "Rate","Amount"],
                       colModel: [
                    {name: "sl", width: 40, align: 'center'},
                    {name: "item", width: 230, align: 'left'},
                    {name: "quantity", width: 100, align: 'center'},
                    {name: "amount", width: 100, align: 'right'},
                    { name: "amountcalculate", width: 60,
                        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
                        {
                            var rq = parseFloat(rowObject[2] );
                            var up = parseFloat(rowObject[3] );
                            return parseFloat(rq * up).toFixed(2);
                        }
                    }
                ],
                height: "100%",
                rowNum: -1,
                sortname: "name",
                footerrow : true,
                idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_"
            });
            debugger
            var $grid = $("#" + subgridTableId);
            var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'amountcalculate', false, 'sum');
            alert(colSum);
            $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 'amountcalculate': parseFloat(colSum)});
        },
```

Comment: Please include in all your questions the information about **the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and the fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The usage of `rowNum: -1` is wrong in old versions of jqGrid. The usage of formatter can be replaced to the usage of `jsonmap`. If you do use custom formatter then you have to specify [unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) too.

Answer (score 0):

Please include in all your questions the information about **the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and the fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The solution can have depend on the information.

I suppose that the origin of your problem is the usage of custom formatter *without* specifying the corresponding unformatter function. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting).

In general, it's better to replace custom formatter to `jsonmap` function, which return the calculated value based on the value of tow other properties. It allows for example to combine the `jsonmap` function with another formatter, for example with `formatter: "currency"`, `formatter: "integer"` and so on.