# Adding a column that is a result of two other columns in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqgrid where i want to show sum of columns in footer. Here Columns are also Sum of other columns and in footer i have to show there Sum.

How to calculate Sum in footer row as it's always coming 0.0?

Here is my jqgrid code.

```
        $("#jqGridQuarterly").jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        url: "/CapacityPlanning/getQuaterlySummary?resourceId=" + resourceId + "&fiscalYear=" + fiscalYear,
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'POST',
        height: 'auto',
        width: 902,
        colNames: ['Name', 'Project', 'Allocation', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'MAN_EMAIL' },
            { name: 'PRD_NAME' },
            { name: '' },
            { name: 'Q1', formatter: sumFmatterQ1, editable: "readonly", align: "center", unformat: unformatterQ1 },
            { name: 'Q2', formatter: sumFmatterQ2, editable: "readonly", align: "center" },
        { name: 'Q3', formatter: sumFmatterQ3, editable: "readonly", align: "center" },
        { name: 'Q4', formatter: sumFmatterQ4, editable: "readonly", align: "center" }
        ],
        //sortname: ["REQ_ID"],
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autowidth: true,
        forceFit: true,
        gridView: true,
        grouping: true,
        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ["MAN_EMAIL"],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupText: [
                "Resource Name: <b>{0}</b>"
            ],
            groupOrder: ["asc"],
            //groupSummary: [true],
            //groupSummaryPos: ["header"],
            groupCollapse: false
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            var grid = $("#jqGridQuarterly")

            $('#jqGridQuarterly td').each(function () {
                var thisText = $(this).text();
                if ($(this).text() == 'TOTAL') {
                    $(this).parent().css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    $(this).parent().css('background', '#E0E0E0');

                }
                if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 20) {
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                }

                sumJan = grid.jqGrid("getCol", "Q1", false, "sum");
                sumFeb = grid.jqGrid("getCol", "Q2", false, "sum");
                sumMar = grid.jqGrid("getCol", "Q3", false, "sum");
                sumApr = grid.jqGrid("getCol", "Q4", false, "sum");

                grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', {
                    PRD_NAME: 'Total Allocation:',
                    Q1: sumJan,
                    Q2: sumFeb,
                    Q3: sumMar,
                    Q4: sumApr
                });
            });
        },

        rowNum: 1000

    });
```

I am using custom formatter and i saw many posts which advice using unformatter as  well , here is the code for that also.

```
    function sumFmatterQ1(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        options;
        var jan = parseFloat(rowObject.EST_JAN || 0);
        var feb = parseFloat(rowObject.EST_FEB || 0);
        var mar = parseFloat(rowObject.EST_MAR || 0);
        debugger;
        return (jan + feb + mar).toFixed(1);

    }
    function unformatterQ1(cellvalue, options) {
        return cellvalue;
    }
```

I am using jqGrid  version 4.6.0 . I saw similar question but didn't get any answer from it 
[adding a jqgrid column that is a result of two other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360886/adding-a-jqgrid-column-that-is-a-result-of-two-other-columns)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @TonyTomov Not able to show sum in footer row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to disable userDataOnFooter i.e set it to false. userData OnFooter means that the sum is performed at server and this data is transported with your source data and placed direct to the grid without any operation from your side.

Second in your gridComplete event you loop over all grid cells to to sum a row(s) with getCol which do the same - this will cause a lot of performance problems and is bad as concept.

Moreover you can use summaryType and summaryTpl in colModel to do the same and discard the code in gridComplete. [See this example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/summary_and_grand_total/index.html)

I'm suggesting you to see the [old docs here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping)

**UPDATE**

Sorry I do not see some additional conditions.

In your case the the main problem is in the formatter and in the way you set the summary value with footerData.

As you know the footerData uses the colModel to set a value in the footer, but your colModel does not contain EST_JAN and etc. In order to make summary shown in the footer you will need to chack for these fiellds in the formatter and if they not exists to use the definition in from The colModel.

The second note is the use of grid complete and the loop

```
$('#jqGridQuarterly td').each(function () {...
```

in this loop you youe on evey cell the summing with getColl, which causes incredibla slowdown of the code in case of a lot of table data.

The sum should be performed only once.

Last but not least, you should not use name in colModel with empty value.

Below is a working code with only one formatter.You will need to change the other accordancy:

```
function sumFmatterQ1(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    if(rowObject.EST_JAN && rowObject.EST_FEB && rowObject.EST_MAR) {
        var jan = parseFloat(rowObject.EST_JAN || 0);
        var feb = parseFloat(rowObject.EST_FEB || 0);
        var mar = parseFloat(rowObject.EST_MAR || 0);
        return (jan + feb + mar).toFixed(1);
    } else {
        return cellvalue;
  }
}
    function unformatterQ1(cellvalue, options) {
        return cellvalue;
    }
    var mydata =[
        {MAN_EMAIL:"my@email.com", EST_JAN: 10, EST_FEB: 1, EST_MAR : 3},
        {MAN_EMAIL:"my@email.com", EST_JAN: 10, EST_FEB: 1, EST_MAR : 3},
        {MAN_EMAIL:"my@email.com", EST_JAN: 10, EST_FEB: 1, EST_MAR : 3},
        {MAN_EMAIL:"my@email.com", EST_JAN: 10, EST_FEB: 1, EST_MAR : 3},
        {MAN_EMAIL:"my2@email.com", EST_JAN: 12, EST_FEB: 12, EST_MAR : 13},
        {MAN_EMAIL:"my2@email.com", EST_JAN: 13, EST_FEB: 11, EST_MAR : 23},
        {MAN_EMAIL:"my2@email.com", EST_JAN: 14, EST_FEB: 11, EST_MAR : 33},
    ];
$("#jqGridQuarterly").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data : mydata,
        url: "/CapacityPlanning/getQuaterlySummary?resourceId=",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'POST',
        height: 'auto',
        width: 902,
        colNames: ['Name', 'Project', 'Allocation', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'MAN_EMAIL' },
            { name: 'PRD_NAME' },
            { name: '111' },
            { name: 'Q1', formatter: sumFmatterQ1, editable: false, align: "center", unformat: unformatterQ1 },
            { name: 'Q2', editable: "readonly", align: "center" },
        { name: 'Q3',  editable: "readonly", align: "center" },
        { name: 'Q4',  editable: "readonly", align: "center" }
        ],
        //sortname: ["REQ_ID"],
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autowidth: true,
        forceFit: true,
        gridView: true,
        grouping: true,
        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ["MAN_EMAIL"],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupText: [
                "Resource Name: <b>{0}</b>"
            ],
            groupOrder: ["asc"],
            //groupSummary: [true],
            //groupSummaryPos: ["header"],
            groupCollapse: false
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            var grid = $("#jqGridQuarterly")

            $('#jqGridQuarterly td').each(function () {
                var thisText = $(this).text();
                if ($(this).text() == 'TOTAL') {
                    $(this).parent().css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    $(this).parent().css('background', '#E0E0E0');

                }
                if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 20) {
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            });

                sumJan = grid.jqGrid("getCol", "Q1", false, "sum");
                //sumFeb = grid.jqGrid("getCol", "Q2", false, "sum");
                //sumMar = grid.jqGrid("getCol", "Q3", false, "sum");
                //sumApr = grid.jqGrid("getCol", "Q4", false, "sum");
                $(this).jqGrid('footerData', 'set', {
                    PRD_NAME: 'Total Allocation:',
                    Q1: sumJan,
                    //Q2: sumFeb,
                    //Q3: sumMar,
                    //Q4: sumApr
    });
    },
    rowNum: 1000
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guriddo/nw7c34zt/)

Enjoy

Comment: summaryType will show only group sums, rather i want all the column sum?

Comment: Thank you very much.i will keep the advice you just passed.